# Score of MongoDB text search is indifferent to the order of found tokens

Tags: mongodb, text-search

I am using MongoDB text search. I see that the score of the result is indifferent to the order of the found tokens.
For example:

1. I am using a text search on the phrase: "aaa ccc"
2. In mongo, I have two documents as follows:

   - "aaa bbb ccc ddd"
   - "ccc bbb aaa ddd"

The text search found both documents, with the same score. Can I modify the search (or the index) so the first document will get a higher score? Is there any workaround this issue?

Thanks
H Guy

Comment: Could you add the query?

Comment: db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "aaa ccc" } } )

Comment: Have you tried? db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "aaa ccc" } }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ) .sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )

Comment: Both documents have the same score. Therefore sorting does not help